# rake db:migrate hangs in master environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I try to execute `rake db:migrate` command but it hangs, I found similar posts but couldn't get any proper solution.
I can execute this on the development environment without any problem but on master it hangs:

```
bundle exec bin/rake db:migrate   RAILS_ENV=master
==  AddPublishToPages: migrating ==============================================
-- add_column(:pages, :publish, :boolean)
```

I executed the command and waited around 60 minutes but I get nothing and this is what the `log/master.log` shows:

```
Migrating to AddPublishToPages (20150108140428)
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
```

ruby,rails rake versions:

```
ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]
--

bin/rake --version
rake, version 10.0.4
--

bin/rails --version
Rails 3.2.12

bundle -v
Bundler version 1.1.3
```

any idea?

Comment: what kind of error you get? Can you post trace of log?

Comment: If the pages table is large, adding a column will take a long time.  Changes which affect an entire table are generally very slow, and grow slower as the amount of data that is affected increases.

Comment: Can you try it with an empty database too? Also, did you set up properly the 'master' environment under the `config/environments` folder?

Comment: The table is very small, its not large. The configuration is fine i didnt have this issue in the past. It just hangs and then i get timeout error

Comment: Check in the `log/master.log` file; it should show more details about what happens when `bundle exec bin/rake db:migrate   RAILS_ENV=master` is run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem resolved, the issue was that there were many lock sessions on that specific table thats why `rake db:migrate` was not able to gain access on that specific table. So executing the below query showed the number of lock sessions on the table:

```
SELECT *
  FROM pg_locks l
  JOIN pg_class t ON l.relation = t.oid AND t.relkind = 'r'
 WHERE t.relname = 'pages';
```

So I just restarted the `postgresql` server and the problem resolved.